# Having a problem executing simulink from GUI, anyone knows what's the matter?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, simulink, matlab-guide, matlab-deployment

I'm trying to plot "t vs y" setting some values from the edit texts in GUI, between one of them the "tfinal" as the Stop Time, but when I run the code does not replace it and shows the next error when trying to replace it: (*Hope you can help me)

```
Error evaluating expression 'tfinal' for 'StopTime' specified in the Configuration Parameters dialog for
block diagram 'gui_sim_model'.
.
.
.
Error in
matlab.graphics.internal.figfile.FigFile/read>@(hObject,eventdata)gui_adv_sim('pushbutton1_Callback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))
- Show complete stack trace
Caused by:
    Error using gui_adv_sim>pushbutton1_Callback (line 184)
    Unrecognized function or variable 'tfinal'. - Showcomplete stack trace
        Error using gui_adv_sim>pushbutton1_Callback
        (line 184)
        Variable 'tfinal' has been deleted from base workspace.
```

Code in Gui (Button):

```
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)


global tfinal vfinal a b t y

tfinal = str2double(get(handles.tf,'String'));
vfinal = str2double(get(handles.vf,'String'));

a = str2double(get(handles.aval,'String'));
b = str2double(get(handles.bval,'String'));


sim('gui_sim_model');

axes(handles.axes1)
plot(t,y)

xlabel('time in seconds')
ylabel('value of y')
```

Simulink:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/IchLG.png

Interface: https://i.stack.imgur.com/T08lf.png

Comment: Seems likely that the variable 'tfinal' was used in the Simulink model and also in the GUI, and so they conflict. Good example of why you should avoid using global variables unless absolutely necessary.